# how to choose a specific version of library in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-glide

I need a specific version of Glide 3.8 but in android only appears me 4.0

annex my bookstores

[image]

e seen that when adding a library are added several versions, you can change to one of them?

cache of glide library

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your build.gradle (Module:app) file :

```
compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '3.8.0'
```

And remove your jar archive